# "module" object not callable in Streamlit_lottie

Tags: python, module, python-requests, streamlit, lottie

```py
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
Traceback:
File "c:\users\lucy22\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\streamlit\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 554, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "main.py", line 36, in <module>
    st_lottie(coding)
```

I am trying to add a lottie file to my website however I am getting this error. I would really appreciate some help

I have followed these steps:

```
import streamlit_lottie as st_lottie

import requests
```

```
def load_lottieurl(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    if r.status_code !=200:
        return None
    return r.json()

coding = load_lottieurl("https://assets3.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_3rwasyjy.json")
```

```
with right_column:
    st_lottie(coding)
```

Comment: As the message says, `st_lottie` is a module. What are you actually trying to call?

Comment: I am trying to add a Lottie file(it's a json) file

Comment: Use `from streamlit_lottie import st_lottie`

Answer (score 0):

Adding this even if it is answered on the comment section.
Import:

```
from streamlit_lottie import st_lottie
```

Insted of:

```
import streamlit_lottie as st_lottie
```